# Word for person always after what he does not have and not cherishing what he has

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Term for “constantly unsatisfied soul”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39886/term-for-constantly-unsatisfied-soul)

Is there a word for a person who is always after what he does not have and does not cherish what he has? If not, any idiom or phrase?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My intention has nothing to do with unsatisfaction. Bjorn's answer more or less shares what is in my mind.

Comment: @FumbleFingers For example, an unsatisfied person is always looking for something better in life, which is not necessarily true in my case. In my case, they just tend to ignore what they possess and pursue whatever is not in their pocket yet(not necessarily something good, and often hard to obtain).

Comment: I find it hard to imagine a constant desire for new things *and* lack of appreciation for existing things, without including the concept of dissatisfaction. I suppose *kleptomanic*, and *magpie*, for example, might be steering in that direction, but @Bjorn's answer fits both questions equally well to my mind (or doesn't, since both ask for a single word).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No single word comes to mind (though I wouldn't be surprised if such a word does exist) but a certain well known proverb does:

*The grass is always greener on the other side.*

The [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/The+grass+is+always+greener+on+the+other+side) defines this as *People always think they would be happier in a different set of circumstances. (Usually implies that the other circumstances really are not any better.)*

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like an *ingrate* to me.

If to be *grateful* is exhibit these qualities:

> appreciative of benefits received : willing or anxious to acknowledge
>   and repay or give thanks for benefits

Then an ingrate exhibits exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

A **malcontent** is such a person. Relevant excerpt from *The Free Dictionary* (formerly *The Free Online Dictionary*):

> [mal·con·tent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malcontent) (măl′kən-tĕnt′). [...] *n.* **1.** A chronically dissatisfied person.

Answer (score 0):

To covet something is to want what you don't have, and implicitly conveys that you are not satisfied with what you already have.