# What is the word for one who refuses to capitulate the status quo?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms

What are some alternative words/phrases for one who refuses to capitulate the status quo?

Similarly question for the capitulators of the status quo.

Alternatives I came up with are progrssionalist (positive for improving on the status quo) and, mundane perpetrators for the capitulators.

Comment: FYI, "capitulate" is intransitive. Do you mean someone who doesn't like changing with the status quo or someone who refuses to conform to society's expectations?

Comment: @Kevin : someone who goes with the status quo, like sheeps in a heard.

Comment: -1 shows no research effort. Also polling / requesting lists: voting to close Not Constructive.

Comment: @ΜετάEd : Google did not come up with anything using number of variant related searches, if you have alternative ways of research please share.  Thanks

Comment: You need to *show* your research, then. You also need to explain what you mean by "capitulate to the status quo", because *capitulate* is a **very** unusual word to use with regard to an ongoing situation rather than a transitory or opportunistic threat.

Comment: -1 because made-up word *progerssionalist* is difficult to pronounce and because *capitulators of the status quo* is a nonsensical phrase.  Of course, *mundane perpetrators for the capitulators* is an awfully good phrase that almost makes up for the other problems, but not quite.

Comment: @jwpat7 : That was meant to be progrssionalist, sorry for the typo. People who want progression rather than a stale state of existence.

Comment: @AndrewLeach : Capitulate as having surrendered to the current state that things are, rather than trying to improve on things. Having a sheepish existence, i.e. just following the crowd without attempting to add anything new. I am not sure how to add the google results that I have not find to be close to what I am asking, or the dictionary (non) results as a proof of research. Most likely I will have better luck in German language QA instead.

Comment: @Arjang. You can edit your own post, rather than stating the typo in the comments. Oh and the word you are trying to write is (presumably) progr_e_ssionalist, although the dictionary doesn't think this is a real word http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/progressionalist?s=ts

Comment: *[Progressive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/progressive#Noun)*,  “A person who actively favors or strives for progress towards improved conditions, as in society or government”, may serve better than does *progressionalist*.

Comment: “Capitulate the status quo” and “capitulators of the status quo” are nonsense phrases.  Instead use  “capitulate to the status quo” and “capitulators to the status quo”.  Note added word *to* in first phrase and changed preposition in the other.

Comment: @Arjang: Alternative ways of research? How about a dictionary, a thesaurus, or Wikipedia? Do you really mean to imply that Google is the only way to do research on phrases?  Moreover, I always recommend telling us what you learned, even if your research was unfruitful (e.g., "I tried Googling X, but, after looking through the results, the closest thing I could find was Y, but that doesn't work because..."). Otherwise, what makes you think that we won't spend our time running the same unproductive queries? At least let us start off where you finished up.

Comment: @J.R. : implicitely dictionary, a thesaurus, or Wikipedia all come under the google search, but I assumed there might be an already a well known phrase encapsulating the idea.

Comment: @Arjang: You might like to look at [this related earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39886/term-for-constantly-unsatisfied-soul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For refusing to capitulate the status quo, "rebel" seems appropriate.
For those that do, I'd suggest "conformist"