# What do you call a person who is never content with anything that is given to him?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective for a person who, no matter what you give him/her (materially or otherwise), is never content and always expects more.

Comment: The nouns 'ingrate' and 'malcontent' exist, but I'd call that person ungrateful.

Comment: Even I thought of ungrateful !! But I feel that ungrateful refers more to a person lacking gratitude !!!

Comment: ungrateful [AHDEL]: adj. 
1. Not feeling or exhibiting gratitude, thanks, or appreciation. //gratitude [Collins]: a feeling of thankfulness or appreciation, as for gifts or favours // thankfulness - warm friendly feelings of gratitude [Farlex] //content: adjective 1. in a state of peaceful happiness. [Google D]

Comment: So are we looking for adjectives or nouns now? And if there are some words that you already have considered but dismissed, write them down so people don't have to propose them all over again.

Comment: *Unsatisfiable*, which is beyond currently *unsatisfied*.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Also related [Term for “constantly unsatisfied soul”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39886/term-for-constantly-unsatisfied-soul)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider "***insatiable***" (if he can't find *satisfaction*), "***unappeasable***" (if you can't ever make him *happy*), or just good, old-fashioned "***greedy***" (or, if he's a child, the juvenile equivalent: a "[***spoiled brat***](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiled_child)").

All definitions from MacMillan:

> [***insatiable***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/insatiable): *always wanting more and never feeling satisfied*
>
> [***unappeasable***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/unappeasable): *not able to be pacified, placated, or satisfied.; syn: **implacable***
>
> [***greedy***](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/greedy): *marked by greed :  having or showing a selfish desire for wealth and possessions*