# What's the word for someone who doesn't appreciate what he has and wants more?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What's the word for someone who is ungrateful/ not appreciative of the things he has but wants more lavish things? For example, instead of appreciating the little things he has in his life, someone might go on and on, complaining about things like how the scratch on his brand new shoe ruined his day or who wants a new car while complaining about his old one.

Comment: Sounds like entitled or the old fashioned 'spoiled brat.'

Comment: I don't think this is an duplicate.

Comment: @PV22 You could post a question on our meta explaining why you feel it is not a duplicate.

Comment: @tchrist I am unsure how to formulate this disapproval of a duplicate flag as a question for meta. Would you mind sharing a similar post you are familiar with to help me arrange the question properly? [Link to Meta post regarding this question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10414/whats-the-word-for-someone-who-doesnt-appreciate-what-he-has-and-wants-more)

Comment: "One percenter"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call a person who is never content with anything that is given to him?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192521/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-never-content-with-anything-that-is-given-to-hi)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't appreciate what you have you are simply **ungrateful**.

I think **ungrateful** is the best word for this state of mind.

**Ingrate**, though old-fashioned, is also a good possibility.

> **Ingrate**
> [in-greyt]
> /noun
>
> 1. an ungrateful person.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ingrate)

Comment: UV - **Ingrate**. The key here is that it is a noun, so it directly applies to "a word for someone...".

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, I would use the word/adjective "discontented." A discontented person is an individual who is never satisfied in this life and miserably fails to appreciate things around him. His insatiable appetite for “more,” blindfolds him to his current belongings - tangible and intangible. A discontented person is also a “whiner” as he continues expressing his displeasure in the form of petty complaints, despite having all the life essentials.

**Discontent** (noun); **Discontented** (adjective).

OED definition:

Dissatisfaction with one's circumstances; lack of contentment.

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/discontent)

Comment: The definition you quote (and my sense of the word) does not _imply_ that the discontentment is _unreasonable_ (i.e. "_an individual who is never satisfied_"). _Some_ discontented people might be greedy ingrates, but some might just have had a bad deal and their sense of discontentment may be justified.

Answer (score 1):

Though I think that "ingrate" is probably the best term for the person, to help describe the behavior you may want to consider "obnoxious".

> **Obnoxious**
>   [uh b-nok-shuh s] 
>   /adjective
>
> 1. highly objectionable or offensive; odious:
>      obnoxious behavior.
> 2. annoying or objectionable due to being a showoff or attracting undue attention to oneself.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/obnoxious?s=t)

Answer (score 0):

**Whiner** is perhaps one of the words that could be used to describe the attributes mentioned in the question. It is a noun form of **whine**, which means:

> 2. to snivel or complain in a peevish, self-pitying way:
>
> *He is always whining about his problems.*

[Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/whiner)